# convert csv column data type

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, dataframe

I have a csv sheet with 2 columns:

```
Subject,Exam_Date
Maths,4/13/2017
Physics,4/15/2016
English,42936
```

In this example the `42936` is actually `7/20/2017`. Since the Excel cell data type was general the value got changed to `42936`.

I have a python script to read this csv file. Now I need to convert the `Exam_date` column type to a date while reading the csv file into a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xlrd.xldate_as_tuple` to convert the number to date tuple, then feed to `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
import xlrd
df=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
converted_date = [ e if '/' in e else datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(int(e),0)) for e in df["Exam_Date"] ]
df["Exam_Date"] = converted_date
df
```

df will be :

```
    Subject Exam_Date
0   Maths   2017-04-13
1   Physics 2016-04-15
2   English 2017-07-20
```

Comment: one related question. If i want to write new value to the same csv file. how can i do that?

Comment: @hr02 You could add new rows into the dataframe df, then write the new dataframe to csv file with [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), note set index=False in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `converters`.

```
import xlrd
In [44]: def converter(x):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         return xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(int(x), 0)
    ...:     except (ValueError, TypeError):
    ...:         return x
    ...:     

In [45]: pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'Exam_Date': converter})
Out[45]: 
   Subject  Exam_Date
0    Maths 2017-04-13
1  Physics 2016-04-15
2  English 2017-07-20
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use read_table with delimiter as "," along with literal_eval as functions for converting values in the concerned columns.

```
recipes = pd.read_table("\souravD\PP_recipes.csv", sep=r',', names=["id", "i", "name_tokens", "ingredient_tokens", "steps_tokens", "techniques","calorie_level","ingredient_ids"], converters = {'name_tokens' : literal_eval, 'ingredient_tokens' : literal_eval, 'steps_tokens' : literal_eval, 'techniques' : literal_eval, 'ingredient_ids' : literal_eval},header=0)
```

[Recipes dataframe after changing datatype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRop0.jpg)